# Reset Seekbar not in android by click

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to reset **seekbar** value to return to default one it starts with e.g zero value

my current view is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIA0q.png)

needed view is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RelZ8.png)

I'm using `seekBar.setProgress(0);`

but not working well [**as expected**] any suggestion?

Notes:

1. I set max value in runtime
2. Seekbar is flipped 180 degrees that mean zero value is at right

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android SeekBar set progress value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792888/android-seekbar-set-progress-value)

Comment: not help me also

Comment: Add more context, are you doing this on startup, on the action of a button?

Comment: on action button

Comment: Try: pb.setMax(100); pb.setProgress(0);

Comment: Also, the second picture looks like its progress is 100 and not 0

Comment: not work too :(

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos I created rotated seekbar by 180 degree that means zero value at right and 100 value at left

Answer (score 0):

add below attribute in seekbar elements(your xml layout)

```
android:max="100"
```

then find seekbar view and use below code for second image

```
//or Instead of the above code  seekBar.setMax(100);
seekBar.setProgress(100);
```

Comment: not help me. I put max value in runtime too look, I edited te post

Comment: first test flipped 180 degrees white 'android:layoutDirection="rtl"'
then test.
and you can Enter your full code in the question that Others can help better.

Comment: the app does not support rtl  it just flipped by 180 as client need that, this is not the issue my issue is that setProgress not work as expected